# I cannot show several valuables when I use for loop at ect file as template on Node.js(express)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

On Node.js(express), I am developing application. 
I want to show the several valuables by using foor loop at ect file, however it returns 500 error.

When I send single value to ect file(when I don't use for loop at ect file), it doesn't return any error, therefore I am sure that the for loop should be the problem.

The following is the router and view files.
Could you give me some advice?

**items**

```
[ { price: 400,
    order_user: [],
    created: Wed Nov 11 2015 12:14:58 GMT+0900 (JST),
    name: 'test1',
    _id: 5641d1ffe007be5e6bf4d26c },
  { price: 400,
    order_user: [],
    created: Wed Nov 11 2015 12:14:58 GMT+0900 (JST),
    name: 'test2',
    _id: 5641d207e007be5e6bf4d26d },
  { price: 430,
    order_user: [],
    created: Wed Nov 11 2015 12:14:58 GMT+0900 (JST),
    name: 'test3',
    _id: 5641d211e007be5e6bf4d26e } 
]
```

**index.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var model = require('../model/product.js');
var Product = model.Product;

router.get('/', function(req, res, next){
   Product.find({}, function(err, items){
     console.log(items);
     res.render('index', { title: 'title', items:items})
   });
});

module.exports = router;
```

**views/index.ect**

```
<!doctype html>
<% extend 'layout' %>
<ul>
  <% for item in items : %>
    <li><= item.name %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var session = require('express-session');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var login = require('./routes/login');
var register_product = require('./routes/register_product');
var collection = require('./routes/collection');

var ECT = require('ect');

var app = express();
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);

app.engine('ect', ECT({ watch: true, root: __dirname + '/views', ext: '.ect' }).render);
app.set('view engine', 'ect');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(session({
  secret: 'keyboard cat',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  store: new MongoStore({
        db: 'session',
        host: 'localhost',
        clear_interval: 60 * 60
    }),
  cookie: {
    httpOnly: false,
    maxAge: 30 * 60 * 1000 // 30min.
  }
}));

//routing
app.use('/login', login);
app.get('/users', users);
app.get('/collection', collection);
app.get('/register_product', register_product);

app.get('/', routes);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: Just as a note for further learning. `items` is a javascript object and not JSON. JSON is a well defined format that requires e.g. that the keys of the object are double quoted.

Comment: Dear t.niese
Thank you for teaching it. I've edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem. It seems that, at ect file. valuable should be attached with '@'.

**views/index.ect**

```
<!doctype html>
<% extend 'layout' %>
<ul>
  <% for item in @items : %>
    <li><%= item.name %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```